# Compiling a cpp file with vscode, in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) on how to get started with c++ and vscode in ubuntu.

I have gcc already installed with the latest version.
Running `sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1.1).
build-essential set to manually installed.
gdb is already the newest version (9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1).
gdb set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

However, when I get to the stage of creating the config file, I have no option for  `C/C++: g++ build active file`. I only have [image: these options]

So, I choose /usr/bin/cpp.Then I build the file, and get the success message.
However, when run the newly created executable file, I get several error messages:

```
./helloworld: line 17: namespace: command not found
./helloworld: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./helloworld: line 23: `  typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;'
```

the strange thing is that the lines with code in the helloworld file end on line 16, so I think there's something wrong with the compiler...

Comment: Honestly, I always found it easier to use Cmake or a makefile when compiling on platforms other than Windows.

Comment: Doubt there is something wrong with the compiler, more likely something wrong with the vs code build system. I imagine if you compiled on the command line it would work just fine.

Comment: @Taekahn You're right... I just copied the tasks.json from the tutorial, and overwrote the previous version. Then I ran the executable, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Its best to get GCC working in your commandline, then get it working using VS Code tasks.

---

I suggest that you create the most simplistic project structure you can. Use only a project directory, and a single file named `main.cpp`.

###### Something that looks like this:

```
    PROJECT (dir)  // path = ./
      │
      └──> main.cpp (file)  // path = ./main.cpp
```

###### Once you have a directory with `main.cpp` do 1 of 2 things:

1. Use the following command to add a Hello World example to your **`main.cpp`** file.

```
  $> echo -e "\n#include <iostream>\n\nusing namespace std;\n\nint main()\n{\n   cout << \"Hello World\!\" << endl;\n}" > main.cpp
```

---

2. Or copy and paste the code below into **`main.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

> ###### FYI: You should be doing this from the command-line not vscode (not until you create the vscode task which I will show bellow)

Another thing to note, is your commandline should be pointed to your project directory, the directory you created with `main.cpp` in it.

From inside your project directory execute the following command.

```
$> g++ ./main.cpp -o build
```

if your file compiled & built your executable correctly you should be able to use the `ls` command to see a new file named build in your project directory.

If all went well, the new `build` file is an executable. Execute it by entering...

```
$> ./build
```

and you should see "Hello World!"

At this point use the following command...

```
$> code .
```

###### VS Code should open to your projects directory.

Now using vscode create another directory, and name it **`./.vscode`**

Then add a file to the **`./.vscode`** directory named **`tasks.json`**

The files full pathname will be: `./.vscode/tasks.json`

then you will want to add the following to your tasks file

```
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "GCC: My Compilation Task",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": ["-g", "./main.cpp", "-o", "./build"],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "/usr/bin"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

then you should be able to press <kbd>F1</kbd> and type **`RUN TASK`**, when you see the option in the quick menu that says **`RUN TASK`** click it, and then select the tasks with the same name as the label key in your `tasks.json` file, which is **`"GCC: My Compilation Task"`**

Comment: @j D3V The tasks file entry appears to be missing an opening curly bracket `{` at the start.

Comment: Using the suggested tasks.json entry gives the following error (on Ubuntu 22.04): 
`cc1plus: fatal error: ttt.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-c', '/usr/bin/g++ -g ttt.cpp -o ./ttt'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).`
However, it works correctly if I enter the full path in "args", e.g.:
`"args": ["-g", "/home/matthew/Repos/TinyTimetablingToy/ttt.cpp", "-o", "/home/matthew/Repos/TinyTimetablingToy/ttt"],`

Comment: @mathew Thats becuase I left the `./` off of `main.cpp`, try it now.